# how to return a default value in sqlite table for non matching rows of a select statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, triggers

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE count_data(
    date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (date('now', 'localtime')),
    count INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

I'd like to query for "count" on a given day, if no data exists I'd like it to return "0" value.

(i plan on using this table later for rollup)

I've tried several variations but can't get it to work (no result is returned):

```
SELECT ifnull(count,0) from count_data where date = date('now', 'localtime');

SELECT count is null from count_data where date = date('now', 'localtime');

SELECT COALESCE(count,1) from count_data where date = date('now', 'localtime');
```

Comment: Your table definition allows duplicates for `date`. So if data exists for a given date you want all the rows for that date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select coalesce(sum(count), 0) from count_data where date = date('now', 'localtime');
```

This is an aggregation query without a `group by` clause, so it is guaranteed to return one row. If you have maximum one row per date, then the `sum()` returns the only available value (or `0`).

If you don't want aggregation, an alternative is `union all`:

```
select count from count_data where date = date('now', 'localtime')
union all
select 0 where not exists (select 1 from count_data where date = date('now', 'localtime')
```

Comment: I'd rather not aggregate as i thought of adding a trigger which could increment the count field per day when an insert had occured on a corresponding table